# Ascoli-Arzela Theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Generalizations) gives the Ascoli-Arzela theorem for a Compact Hausdorff Space. Following through the proof sketch at the end of the linked section, I could not find where the Hausdorff property is used. The reference, Dunford & Schwartz also seems to say that Hausdorff property is not required. Is it true that the Hausdorff property is not required in the theorem?

Thanks,

Comment: Hausdorff is not required.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20670/theorem-of-arzel%C3%A0-ascoli).