# Generalizations of Arzela Ascoli theorem

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $C(X,Y)$ be the space of continuous functions on two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$. If $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of functions of $C(X,Y)$ are there any conditions on $X$ or $Y$  such that an analogous formation of Arzela Ascoli shows that $\mathcal{F}$ is precompact(compact if closed).

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  You can prove a version of the theorem that says that $\mathcal{F}$ is compact if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous and
$$
\overline{\{f(x) : f \in \mathcal{F}\}} \subseteq Y \text{ is compact for each } x \in X.
$$
The space $X$ can even be swapped for a locally compact Hausdorff space.  You can [take a look here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20670/theorem-of-arzel%C3%A0-ascoli) for references.