# A sequence of curves $(x_n)$ for which $g(\dot{x}_n, \dot{x}_n)$ is uniformly bounded converges weakly in $H^1([0, 1], M)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(M, g)$ be a complete Riemannian Manifold of dimension $d$ and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\Omega = \{x \in C^1([0, 1], \ M): \ x(0) = p, \quad x(1) = q, \quad \dot{x}(0) = v, \quad \dot{x}(1) = w \}$ such that $g(\dot{x}_n, \dot{x}_n)$ is uniformly bounded. I've recently read and proven that there exists a subsequence—say $(x_{n_k})$—which converges uniformly to a continuous curve $x: [0, 1] \to M$ with $x(0) = p$ and $x(1) = q$ (see my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783056/uniform-boundedness-and-the-arzela-ascoli-theorem-in-a-riemannian-manifold/3783116#3783116)).

However, the paper I'm reading goes on to say that "the boundedness of $g(\dot{x}_n, \dot{x}_n)$ also implies that $x$ is of Sobolev class $H^1$ and that the convergence of $(x_{n_k})$ to $x$ is weak in the $H^1$ sense." For the sake of consistency, they've defined $H^1([0, 1], M)$ as the space of curves $\gamma: [0, 1] \to M$ such that, if $(U, \phi)$ is a local coordinate chart on $M$ and $I \subset [0, 1]$ closed is such that $\gamma(I) \subset U$, then $\phi \circ \gamma \in H^1(I, \mathbb{R}^d)$. I.e., all local representatives of $\gamma$ are continuous with weak derivative in $L^2([0,1], \mathbb{R}^d)$.

This goes a bit over my head, and all attempts at consulting the literature thus far have failed. I'm hoping that someone could explain why this is true. My thoughts are below.

---

Given the definition of $H^1$, it seems wise to work within charts and then (hopefully) glue everything together nicely in the end. To that end, choose a finite partition of $[0, 1]$, say $I_j$, and a corresponding family of charts $(U_j, \phi_j)$ covering the image of $x$ such that for sufficiently large $n$ we have $x_{n}(I_j) \subset U_j$. By construction, $\phi_j \circ x_{n} \in C^1(I_j, \mathbb{R^d})$. As far as I understand, $$||\phi_j \circ x_n||_{H^1} = ||\phi_j \circ x_n||_{L^2} + ||(\phi_j \circ x_n)'||_{L^2} = \left(\int_0^1 ||(\phi_j \circ x_n)(t)||^2_{\mathbb{R}^d}dt\right)^{1/2} + \left(\int_0^1 ||(\phi_j \circ x_n)'(t)||^2_{\mathbb{R}^d}dt\right)^{1/2}$$

If we can bound both integrals on the right independent of $n$, then since $H^1$ is a Hilbert space there would exist a weakly convergent subsequence. However, I'm not sure how to bring the uniform boundedness of the Riemannian metric in, how to conclude that the weak convergence is to the same $x$ as before (I imagine the two are related), or how to glue it all back together.

Comment: Choose your charts on compact neighbourhoods of $\Bbb R^n$ so that the metrics on $\Bbb R^n$ and their coordinate images in $M$ are equivalent (I mean bi-Lipschitz). Then since $\|x_n'\|$ is uniformly bounded on $M$ its also uniformly bounded in $\Bbb R^n$ since the two metrics are bilipschitz. You also already know that $\|x_n\|$ is uniformly bounded (since it converges uniformly!) so you can do the same thing.

Comment: @s.harp Thanks for the response. Why is it that the metrics on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and their coordinate images in $M$ will be bi-Lipschitz equivalent in compact chart neighborhoods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets carry out the above comment with more detail and care.

Let $\Psi : U\to \Bbb R^d$ be a (arbitrarily fine) chart and restrict $x_n$ to be contained in the chart. We are interested in seeing why both
$$\int \|\Psi\circ x_n\|^2\quad \text{ and }\quad \int\|(\Psi\circ x_n)'\|^2$$
are bounded above. The first integral is the simplest: We may assume our chart has domain a compact neighbourhood, meaning here that $\overline U$ is compact and that $\Psi$ can be extended to be a chart on a neighbourhood of $\overline{U}$. This implies that $\Psi(U)$ is a bounded set in $\Bbb R^d$ (say with upper bound $C$) and then:
$$\int \|\Psi \circ x_n\|^2 ≤\int C^2 ≤ C^2$$
as the domain of $x_n$ is something in $[0,1]$ (remember we have restricted it). For the second integral we do the same step, this time with the differential $D\Psi$. By compactness of the domain we may assume the differential has bounded modulus (say its bound is $c$) and then:
$$\int \|\Psi \circ x_n)' \|^2 = \int dt\, \|D_{x_n(t)}\Psi\ (x_n'(t))\|^2_{\Bbb R^d}≤\int dt \|D_{x_n}\Psi\|^2\,\|x_n'(t)\|^2_{M}≤c^2\int\|x_n'(t)\|^2_M$$
by assumption $\|x_n'(t)\|$ is uniformly bounded (in $t$ and $n$), hence there is some constant $D$ with $\|x_n'(t)\|≤D$, so in total
$$\int\|(\Psi \circ x_n)'\|^2_{\Bbb R^d}≤ c^2 D^2.$$

This gives the statement. Apply it to your scenario by covering the path of $x$ with finitely many charts having the above property, then all but finitely many $x_n$ are contained in the union of these charts and you get that the sum of the above constants for every chart are a bound for all but finitely many of these integrals.

Comment: The only step that I'm a bit unsure of is $||D_{x_n} \Psi(x_n'(t))||_{\mathbb{R}^d}^2 \le ||D_{x_n} \Psi||_M^2 ||x_n'(t)||_M^2$. Do you define the norm of the differential as $||D_{x_n} \Psi||_M^2 := \sup_{v \in S^d} ||D_{x_n} \Psi(v)||$ where $S^d$ is the unit sphere in the tangent space of $M$ at $x_n(t)$? Then the boundedness of the norm is trivial at a point, and is given uniformly because of the compact domain?

Comment: $D_{x_n(t)}\Psi$ is a linear map $T_{x_n(t)}M\to T_{\Psi(x_n(t))}\Bbb R^d$. The norm is defined by:
$$\|D_{x_n(t)}\Psi\|=\sup_{v\in T_{x_n(t)}M, \|v\|_M≤1}\|D_{x_n(t)}\Psi(v)\|_{\Bbb R^d}$$
The inequality you remark on then follows from sub-multiplicativity of this norm. The boundedness of this operator norm on $U$ then follows from the compact domain.

Comment: Great, that makes sense to me. Thanks for your help!